# Function Ranking in R

Tags: r, rank

I have two columns x and y. I want to have one column which contains the ranking for both columns. I thought about sum both column and then get it ranked, does any one have a function that rank two columns in r?

Many thanks

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to use the rank function as you suggest:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
apply(df1, 2, rank) # 2 columns with separate rankings
rank(rowSums(df1)) # sum by rows first, then rank
rank(rowMeans(df1)) # avg by rows first, then rank (same result!)
```